# WCF Custom SOAP Header Issues

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to implement an endpoint behavior which injects a custom SOAP header into all messages to and from a service.  I've gotten pretty close by implementing the approach from the accepted answer of this question:

[WCF WSDL Soap Header on all operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986455/wcf-wsdl-soap-header-on-all-operations/995951#995951)

After implementing that solution, my custom SOAP header does indeed show up in the WSDL; however, when I try to call the methods on my service, I get the following exception/fault:

```
<ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <HelpLink i:nil="true" />
      <InnerException i:nil="true" />
      <Message>Index was outside the bounds of the array.</Message>
      <StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.AddHeadersToMessage(Message message, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, Object[] parameters, Object result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.SerializeOutputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace>
      <Type>System.IndexOutOfRangeException</Type>
    </ExceptionDetail>
```

Looking in Reflector at the DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.AddHeadersToMessage method thats throwing the exception, leads me to believe that the following snippet is causing the problem...but I'm not sure why.

```
MessageHeaderDescription description = (MessageHeaderDescription) headerPart.Description;
object parameterValue = parameters[description.Index];
```

I think the last line above is throwing the exception. The `parameters` variable is from  [IDispatchFormatter.SerializeReply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageformatter.serializereply.aspx)

What's going on?!?!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: What exactly is the value of description.Index? Is it -1?

Comment: I can't debug into the DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.AddHeadersToMessage method but the MessageHeaderDescription objects I'm injecting all have an Index value of zero.  I suppose this would throw that exception if `parameters` was null or zero-length, but I don't have control over that variable (I don't think)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same example ("[WCF WSDL Soap Header on all operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986455/wcf-wsdl-soap-header-on-all-operations/995951#995951)"), and the same error ocurred. To solve this error, I removed the header from the request on income, in function "AfterReceiveRequest" in IDispatchMessageInspector. I have modified the example in such a way, that the header is added only to incoming messages.

```
[DataContract(Name = "AuthHeader", Namespace = "web")]
public class AuthHeader
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class SoapHeaderEndpointBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior
{
    #region BehaviorExtensionElement Members

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(SoapHeaderEndpointBehavior);
        }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new SoapHeaderEndpointBehavior();
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEndpointBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        var inspector = new FvsMessageInspector();
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        var channelDispatcher = endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher;
        if (channelDispatcher == null)
            return;
        foreach (var ed in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
        {
            var inspector = new FvsMessageInspector();
            ed.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
        }

        foreach (OperationDescription operationDescription in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
        {
            string nmm = operationDescription.Name;
            foreach (MessageDescription msgDescription in operationDescription.Messages)
            {
                if (msgDescription.Direction == MessageDirection.Input)
                {
                    MessageHeaderDescription header = new MessageHeaderDescription("AuthHeader", "web");
                    header.Type = typeof(AuthHeader);
                    msgDescription.Headers.Add(header);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class FvsMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector, IClientMessageInspector
{
    #region IDispatchMessageInspector

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        int i = request.Headers.FindHeader("AuthHeader", "web");
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            AuthHeader header = request.Headers.GetHeader<AuthHeader>(i);
            //Use header info here
            request.Headers.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        //No need to do anything else
    }

    #endregion

    #region IClientMessageInspector

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        //No need to do anything else
    }

    #endregion
}
```

But much simpliers aproach is to use WCFExtrasPlus: "https://wcfextrasplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SOAP%20Headers&referringTitle=Documentation"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the contracts using `IServiceBehavior`, I've found that modifying the exported contract using `IContractBehavior` and `IWsdlExportExtension` works fine and no messages need to be rewritten (like in the other listed answer).