# How can I make the generated service wsdl (wcf service) contain soap headers?

Tags: wcf, soap, soapui

I have developed a WCF service which use SOAP headers as part of the validation of the request process.
In my service side I verify that the SOAP headers sent and valid.
I generated WSDL files using SOAPUI in order to send to my costumer.
When testing the generated wsdls, I noticed that SOAPUI does not add SOAP headers to the requests automatically.
Is there any way to mark the service (with attribute or something similar) like a service which needs SOAP headers?

Thanks

Comment: And how did you add those headers to your requests? How do you validate them?

Comment: This is exactly my question, how can I add them to the requests. I validate by using interceptor in the service side that goes over the headers and validate them

Answer (score 3):

If you are only using some interceptors / inspectors to validate that header is present you cannot expect that it will be mentioned in WSDL. Header is mentioned in WSDL only if it is part of message contract used by your operation or if you add them to [message description manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986455/wcf-wsdl-soap-header-on-all-operations).